# Reference a childitem of a grid defined by a datatemplate in windows 8

Tags: xaml, datatemplate, children, windows-store-apps

I am having a hard time doing the following:

I have a datatemplate which populates a gridview with grids. The number of grids to be generated depends on the data binding, that is how many of the data objects it returns. My grid, which is defined in the datatemplate, contains some controls; namely an image and a textbox.

I am trying to reference the image on the event selectionchanged of the gridview but I am failing majestically. Here is a sample code of what I am trying to do:

The datatemplate (in style.xaml):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="tmplMenu">
  <Grid Width="100"
        Height="100"
        Margin="0,0,10,10">
    <Border Background="{Binding bgColor}" />
    <Image Source="{Binding imgPath}"
           Stretch="None"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The gridview (in mainpage.xaml for example):

```
<GridView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tmplMenu}"
          x:Name="myGrid"
          Margin="50,20,0,50"
          Width="360"
          SelectionChanged="myGrid_SelectionChanged">
  <GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapGrid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Now the selectionChanged event on the gridview (where I would like to reference the image in the datatemplate):

```
private void myGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            /**REFERENCE IMAGE (which is a child item of the generated grid) OF CLICKED GRID (which is a child item of the gridview) HERE **/

        }
```

Here, the selectionChangedEventArgs e returns the data object which is used to generate the grid instead of the grid itself.

Can anyone help me out in referencing the image control of the clicked item?